# Catch an error by producing NA

Tags: r, error-handling

I wish to get NA when a function returns an Error rather than the code halting.

I currently use

```
try.test<-try(results<-lm(log(0)~1))
if(class(try.test)=="try-error"){results<-NA}
```

I also tried playing with tryCatch.

I would like to find a single function/line solution.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try

```
result <- tryCatch(lm(log(0)~1), error=function(err) NA)
```

But this catches all errors, not just those from log(0).

Comment: This is a great little T/F indicator. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

A less than classy, but equally short way of solving your problem.

```
results <- NA
try(results<-lm(log(0)~1), silent = TRUE)
```

If you're looking for an elegant way to handle errors, I recommend looking into the concept of a monad; using these structures reduces the amount of "if(!na(x))...." boilerplate in your scripts.