# R: obtain a specific depth from multi dimension array of depth levels

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, interpolation, netcdf, r-raster

I need to calculate 25 degree isotherm depth from HYCOM data which has temperature of 33 depth levels of ocean in selected area.

I download data from netcdf subset tool using below link

```
http://ncss.hycom.org/thredds/ncss/GLBa0.08/latest/temp?var=temperature&north=25&west=74.1199&east=434.1199&south=-15&horizStride=1&time_start=2016-09-27T00%3A00%3A00Z&time_end=2016-09-27T23%3A59%3A00Z&timeStride=1&vertCoord=&accept=netcdf4
```

data set in netcdf 4 format and imported in to R by ncdf4 library

```
library(ncdf4)
ncdata <- nc_open(file)
lon <- ncvar_get(ncdata, "Longitude")
lat <- ncvar_get(ncdata, "Latitude")
temp <-ncvar_get(ncdata,"temperature")
str(temp)
```

num [1:4500, 1:512, 1:33] 24.7 24.6 24.6 24.7 24.7 ...

How to find depth of specific temperature (25) from above array?Then subset it in to small region?

Comment: Trying to have a look but cannot access the file and data to test. Would be better if you post a working link or a subset of the "temp" variable.

Comment: you could run `apply` over the array with a function to find the depth - at simplest `apply(temp, c(1, 2), finddepth)` where finddepth is a function that will find depth of first value below 25 in one depth profile

Comment: @Lorenzo link is updated now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on @Richard Telford reply, you just have to apply a function on all pixels' z-dimension that computes the depth at which temperature intersects the 25 deg. threshold.

Very simply, you could then do:

```
file <- "http://ncss.hycom.org/thredds/ncss/GLBa0.08/latest/temp?var=temperature&north=25&west=74.1199&east=434.1199&south=-15&horizStride=1&time_start=2016-09-27T00%3A00%3A00Z&time_end=2016-09-27T23%3A59%3A00Z&timeStride=1&vertCoord=&accept=netcdf4"
savefile = tempfile(, fileext = "nc4")
download.file(file, savefile)
library(ncdf4)
ncdata <- nc_open(savefile)
lon <- ncvar_get(ncdata, "Longitude")  
lat <- ncvar_get(ncdata, "Latitude") 
temp <-ncvar_get(ncdata,"temperature")

temp <- temp [,,1:10] # subset depths to speed up
depths <- 1:10  # let's define some dummy depths - you want to put actual values, here !

finddepth = function(pixtemp, ...) {
  if (max(pixtemp, na.rm = TRUE) < predtemp$temp) {
    NA    # set to NA if no values >= 25
  } else {
    depth <- tryCatch({
      depth <- approx(pixtemp, depths,predtemp$temp)$y # interpolate using linear (faster)
      # interp  <- loess(depths~pixtemp)  # interpolate using loess  (slower - deals with non-linearity)
      # depth  <- predict(interp, predtemp$temp) # find depth @ temperature
      return(depth)   # send back computed depth
    }, error = function(e) {NA}
    )

  }
}
predtemp  <- data.frame(temp = 25)   # set desired isotherm
iso_depth <- apply(temp, c(1, 2), FUN = finddepth)
```

which (I think) gives the required data in "iso_depth":

```
library(lattice)
levelplot(iso_depth, main = "Isotherm depth", col.regions = terrain.colors(250))
```

[image]

*(In the image, white areas correspond to point @ which the 25° isotherm doesn't exist because maximum temperature is < 25 °).*

Here I'm using linear interpolation through "approx" to find the depth @ which a straight line between the last depth at which T > 25 and the first @ which T < 25 intersect the T = 25 level. If linear interpolation is not ok for you, you can uncomment the two lines after "depth <- approx(...)" and you will work with loess local quadratic interpolation (which is however slower and give more NA).

Note that in order to have "meaningful" values, you'll have to substitute the dummy "depths" variable I set up with correct depth values.

. Also note that this is quite slow: more complex approaches could give greater speed. You could gain much speed by implementing parallel processing.

@sudheera previous iterations were crashing because there are some pixels with only 3 non NA values,  and the try catch construct had an error.

HTH

Lorenzo

Comment: finddepth function was applied to real data set. But it give errors. Error in predLoess(y, x, newx, s, weights, pars$robust, pars$span, pars$degree,  : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 5)
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

Comment: Depth levels are not equal. depths
 [1]    0   10   20   30   50   75  100  125  150  200  250  300  400  500  600  700  800  900 1000
[20] 1100 1200 1300 1400 1500 1750 2000 2500 3000 3500 4000 4500 5000 5500. As 24 degrees temperature not exists below 200m is it possible to exclude depths below 200m from array before apply function?

Comment: concerning "excluding depths", you can easily do that by subsetting the temp array (e.g., `temp <- temp [,,1:10]`), or using the subsetting capabilities of `ncvar_get` (see the help - that would spare you some memory/time).

Comment: Concerning the error, it's difficult to debug... I suspect that you have some pixels with "strange" temp values or profiles, which causes loess prediction to fail. Does it happen immediately, or after a while ?   One suggestion I could give you is to try to enclose the `depth  <- predict(interp, predtemp$temp)` in a trycatch structure, so that if it fails it sends out NA instead than crashing [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14668972/catch-an-error-by-producing-na)

Comment: Excluding depth is working. error massage appears after few minutes. I tried to use try catch but got same results as previous. is there any simple way to read all the temperature values ( 10 depth values of 10 layers) in a single grid point and find depth value correspond to specific temperature (25) and write x,y,z to data frame in a for loop ?

Comment: Well, that's exactly what the current code is doing, save that "apply" spares you from explicity loop on the data....  Can you share how did you implement the trycatch procedure ?

Comment: depth  <- tryCatch(predict(interp, predtemp$temp),error=function(err) NA)   -- I haven't use that before.

Comment: mmm... Can you try to put trycatch also on the fitting ?  Something like: `depth <- tryCatch({interp <- loess(depths~pixtemp) ;        depth  <- predict(interp, predtemp$temp)},error=function(err) NA)`

Comment: i have shared netcdf file as follows; https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwswfhTezOETVkI1LWY0N25CY00/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'll have a look when I have time. I'd suggest you however to start having a look at the various options available for debugging in "R" [Link here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205612627-Debugging-with-RStudio), so that you can  start to understand WHY the code is crashing (and also how it works).

Comment: Hi. I just updated the answer: now no longer crashing. Also using linear instead than loess interpolation to increase speed.

Comment: TAL! your answer was very helpful.

Comment: can you help on last line of my question too. Longitudes values range from 74.16E to 434.08E (360+74.1) due to hycom model netcdf subseting tool bug. My interested subset is 52E to 92E region and its located in both ends of file. as i only need this subset for final iso_depth, is it possible to subset final matrix? May i ask this as new question?

Comment: sorry, but  how can a longitude be equal to 434° E ?

Comment: Netcdf subset tool (http://ncss.hycom.org/thredds/ncss/grid/GLBa0.08/latest/temp/dataset.html) not give subset of 52E to 92E. but when subset with 74.16E to 434.08E (360+74.1) value i was able to download above image.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39656130/how-to-subset-hycom-data-by-netcdfsubset?rq=1

Comment: L99ked intio the link,  and seems a bug to me.  Did you try contacting the.m?

Comment: I put error on hycom google forum. but no one respond yet. https://groups.google.com/a/hycom.org/forum/#!topic/forum/l1e1GXryYV0

Comment: Wild suggestion: subtract 360 from 52 and put that in the west box....  Maybe....